# Licenses for Microsoft 365 for Business, Shared Computers, & Local Accounts

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, license

I'm transitioning my church from Office perpetual licenses to Microsoft 365 Business Premium. I'm trying to figure out how many licenses I need.

We have twelve computers all running Windows 10. There are six staff assigned to specific computers. All have Microsoft accounts. The remaining computers are shared between staff and volunteers. Volunteers are made of of two groups. Twelve need church email and thus have Microsoft accounts. Other volunteers have local accounts (no Microsoft accounts).

How many licenses of Microsoft 365 do I need? With Office perpetual, I just need one copy for each computer. Simple. With MS 365 BP I need at lest six licensed users. Each user can install Office on up to five computers. That would cover installing on the shared computers.

How does MS 365 work? Can a person without a Microsoft account log onto a shared computer using their local domain account and use Word or Excel?

Any help you great folk have provide is greatly welcome.

Brian
Accidental IT

Comment: “How many licenses of Microsoft 365 do I need?” - Office is licensed per machine. Office 365 shouldn’t be linked to an individual’s email account

Comment: Basde on my knowledge, Microsoft 365 Business Premium is "per user based licensing".

Answer (score 0):

You need a license for each physical device.

A Workstation can only be "shared" by User A logging off for USER B to log on AND use Office (otherwise you would have two users needing a license each.

No need to use a Microsoft Account to use an Office License. I do that here.

Comment: I'm still confused. I know that Office 2019 Pro Plus is a per-device license. Anyone logged onto that device can use Office. But it sounds like Microsoft 365 Business Premium is per-user license. So I have 22 users, 7 of which are staff, another 5 are volunteers that regularly use the computers as part of the finance team, and the rest log on occasionally. Do I need 7, 12, or 22 licenses?

Or can I get 7 licenses for the staff, 1 each for the finance team, sound team, and volunteers?

Comment: On one computer, say with fast user switching, only one person can use Office. They must log off Office before another user can use Office.  I was clear about that in my answer. You need ONE license for ALL active simultaneous users including users taking advantage of fast user switching.